# jquery plugin that returns a new object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, jquery-plugins

I'm creating my first jQuery plugin and want to create the jQuery object, but want to be able to control the object that was just created...

I'm building my plugin following the format recommended here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Here is my test code:

```
(function($){

    var $this = $(this);

    var methods = {
        init : function( options ) {

        //  methods.createDiv();

            $this = $('<div>TEST CONTENT</div>')
                .attr({ 'id':'test' })
                .css({'color':'white','backgroundColor': 'red'})
                .appendTo("body");

            setTimeout(function(){
                    methods.green();
                },
                3000
            );
            return $this;
         },

        green : function( ) {
            $this.css({'backgroundColor': 'green'});
        },
        blue : function( ) {
            $this.css({'backgroundColor': 'blue'});
        }
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function( method ) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
        }
    };

})( jQuery );


$(document).ready(function () { 
    var myTest = $.fn.myPlugin();
    myTest.blue();
});
```

Ultimately, I want to be able to control the newly created div using the myTest variable, but it's not working. I'm sure there are obvious pieces I'm missing and mistakes I'm making, but  that's why I'm posting here.  It's my first plugin, so if anyone could help me get this test code up and running I'd appreciate it.  Currently, firebug report: "TypeError: myTest.blue is not a function"

Comment: study this for some patterns for plugin development: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#jquerypluginpatterns

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Invoke your method as:

```
myTest.myPlugin("blue");
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5p2Ba/

`blue` is not a method of the jQuery object here. You are only binding the `methods` object into a module using a closure.